# HOW TO: Get real-time notifications in Laravel 4 using Iron.io MQ, Push Queues & AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, websocket, push-notification, queue

I've integrated `ironMQ` push queues in my Laravel 4 app for longer running processes. I have some views that perform a `$.get` that might take 30 seconds. I wanted to see what others are doing to easily get notified when `ironMQ` is done pushing back to an endpoint.

An example of what I will be doing with push queues mostly:

```
public function getCompletedTasks() {

    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

    Queue::push(function($job) use ($user) {
        $recent = new Recent;
        $tasks  = $recent->getCompletedTasks($user);
        // append data from $tasks to DOM
        // here's where I want to receive my notification
    });     
}
```

Here I am just getting tasks from an API that match data from user.

I know I can store the response data to a database and use AJAX long polling to constantly check for the data but it seems like too much work for most situations I will need to do this. I don't know much about websockets. What types of things have you guys done in these situations? And if you have any examples that would be very helpful. Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Solved the issue using Pusher. See my answer.

Comment: There's no notifications for when IronMQ successfully pushes to an endpoint, but you can use the error queues feature to know when IronMQ was NOT able to successfully deliver a message. Not sure if that helps for your scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with the help of [Pusher](http://pusher.com). Here's what I did:

Setup my Iron MQ push queue as normal. In `routes.php`:

```
Route::post('queue/push', function() {
    return Queue::marshal();
});
```

Installed [pusher laravel package](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-php-server).

In my controller then I `Queue::push` my data. Inside the closure I trigger a new Pusher channel. This will obviously only trigger when the data has been returned from IronMQ.

```
public function getCompletedTasks() {

    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

    Queue::push(function($job) use ($user) {

        $recent = new Recent;
        $tasks  = $recent->getCompletedTasks($user);

        $pusher = new Pusher('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
        $pusher->trigger('reports', 'get_completed_tasks', array('tasks' => $tasks));

        $job->delete();
    });
});
```

Next in my view I call my AJAX function with no callback since I won't be doing anything else just yet:

```
$.get('account/tasks/completed');
```

Next in my view I initialize Pusher, subscribe to the event and bind `get_completed_tasks` to the Pusher channel. Now we just wait for a response from Pusher which will then allow me to perform the latter part of my original AJAX request:

```
{{ HTML::script('//js.pusher.com/2.1/pusher.min.js') }}
<script>
var pusher  = new Pusher('xxx');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('reports');
    channel.bind('get_completed_tasks', function(data) {
        // do something with the data returned
    });
</script>
```

Once I used Pusher in my app, the rest was a breeze. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: too expensive. is there another way?

Comment: You can roll your own notification server. The free account in sandbox mode might serve your needs. If not I would think the low price of Pusher or similar would far outweigh the cost of provisioning and setting up your own solution.

Comment: you mean that, you are only using the free features? really? cuz im going to try it now. i only need to notify the birthdays. free testing account alone can do this right?

Comment: Obviously they don't recommend it but if that's all you need it for, it would probably suffice.